Pricing of securitised (e.g. CLO) products
I am looking for any appropriate textbooks/references for the pricing of securitisations such as CLOs.
I am looking at a pool of underlying corporate loans (some bonds, some ammortising loans, different tenors, different risks etc) and I am looking to develop some models to estimate certain things like (these are just ideas for now):

Reasonable coupon rates on different tranches of an issued security (say a senior bond with attachment/detachment of 10%/100%).
The fair value of an instrument observed on the market or the fair value of a securitisation of my own portfolio (say for a given weighted average margin/PD/LGD/cross-correlation etc).
Expected net cash flows after the issuance of these securities

This is for a university research project however I am struggling to find resources to know where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.
